# How do I run Capybara on similar pages from command line?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I have nearly identical versions of webapps on different sites.

What I'd like to do is specify the site at command line...

```
cucumber --server server1 --tags @tests
```

....

```
@servers = {'server1' => 'https://www.tests.com', 'server2' => 'https://www.foobar.com'}
```

....

```
Background:
Given I am on {#server1}

Scenario: Happy plan
When I go here
And I see this
Then I get that
```

What is the best way to running the same script on multiple similar websites? Can it be run from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create some config and read it before executing scripts.

Put code for parsing config to *features/support/env.rb*, for example.

Comment: I'm really looking for command line `cucumber --server server1` `cucumber --server server2`

Comment: Ha, actually, this is exactly what I did.

Answer (score 2):

Your best option is to use [an environment variable](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Environment-Variables) for your server name:

`cucumber SERVER=server1 --tags @tests`

You can create a generic step:

```
Given I am on the configured test server
```

Then, in your step definition, you can look that up as you would in any normal Ruby code and set it as Capybara's base URL:

```
Given /^I am on the configured test server$/ do
  server_name = ENV['SERVER']
  url = @servers[server_name] or raise "Unknown test server: #{server_name}"
  Capybara.app_host = url
end
```

Note that when using a remote server, you'll need to use a Capybara driver that supports it, such as Selenium: the default RackTest driver does not. You may also want to set `run_server` to `false`. See https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#calling-remote-servers